# Construction of a bump function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

In my "analysis on manifolds" class, I've met the lemma for the existence of bump function. I'm stuck in the proof. Below is the construction of a bump function.

> Let $A$ be a closed subset of open $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. A smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by
> $$f(t)=\begin{cases}\exp(1/t)&t<0,\\0&t\ge0.\end{cases}$$
> Define $\rho:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ as $\rho(x)=f(|x|^2-1)$. By multiplying an appropriate constant, we may assume that
> $$\rho\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),\quad\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\rho(y)dy=1,\quad\overline{\{x:\rho(x)\neq0\}}\text{ is compact}.$$
> Taking a compact neighborhood $K\subset U$ of $A$ and for $0<\varepsilon<d(K,\partial U)$, the smooth function $\psi$ defined as
> $$\psi(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\chi_K(x-\varepsilon y)\rho(y)dy=\varepsilon^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\chi_K(y)\rho((x-y)/\varepsilon)dy$$
> satisfies $0\le\psi\le1$, $\psi\equiv 1$ on $A$, and the support of $\psi$ is a subset of $U$.

I am stuck in several parts:

- How to verify that $\rho$ is smooth? I guess that $f(|x|^2-1)$ works as a smooth function, but I cannot show it.
- Similarly, how to verify the smoothness of $\psi$?
- In the integral notation, I don't know why $\psi$ is a bump function. The integral becomes $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\chi_K(y)\rho((x-y)/\varepsilon)dy=\int_K \rho((x-y)/\varepsilon))dy,$$
  but is it immediately shown that $\psi\equiv1$ on $A$? I think the integral may become
  $$\int_{B(x,\varepsilon)\cap K}\rho((x-y)/\varepsilon)dy\le\varepsilon^n$$
  even if $x\in A$. What happens if $B(x,\varepsilon)\not\subset K$ for $x\in A$?

Comment: Once you're convinced $f$ is smooth (careful analysis of the behavior at $0$), it follows that $\rho$ is smooth as a composition of smooth functions. For the other two parts, is $A$ assumed bounded (so that a compact neighborhood $K$ exists)? In any case, it looks to me that your third concern is legitimate: We also need $\varepsilon$ smaller than the distance from $A$ to the complement of $K$.

Comment: In the lecture note, it is not mentioned that the set $A$ is bounded. I think the condition should be neened, too. Perhaps the lecture note has some errors. I thought I missed something important, but it would be not. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I have a tiny question: is the map $x\mapsto|x|^2$ smooth? The first one I have been stuck in is that.

Comment: Yes, $|x|^{2}$ is a polynomial in the Cartesian coordinates. :) <> I haven't checked the details, but it does appear we need not assume $A$ is bounded. We _do_ need the distance from $A$ to the complement of $U$ to be positive, however. This is automatic if $A$ is bounded, but not in general.

Comment: Thanks! Your comments are very helpful to study manifold. Have a nice day :-)